# Feedback and Facebook Code Clash somewhere

Tags: jquery, forms, html, facebook-like

I m creating a test page everything was going fine until i add popup facebook like box 
facebook code clash with the feedback form i tried so many hours to resolve that but i can't any one of them is visible i want both to be visible without any error 
here is my code :

```
   <div id="contactable"><!-- contactable html placeholder --></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://boysjoys.com/final/scripts/jquery.validate.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://boysjoys.com/final/scripts/jquery.contactable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://boysjoys.com/final/css/contactable.css" type="text/css" />
<script>$(function(){$('#contactable').contactable({subject: 'feedback URL:'+location.href});});</script>

<!--end contactable -->

<div> </div>

<!-- FACEBOOK WIDGET START -->
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://gj37765.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/[www.gj37765.blogspot.com]jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gj37765.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/%5Bwww.gj37765.blogspot.com%5Dfbpopup.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=flase') == -1) {
var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
$.colorbox({width:"400px", inline:true, href:"#mdfb"});
}
});
</script>
<div style="display:none">
<div id='mdfb' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>

<center>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FBoysJoys&amp;width=300&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=%23ffffff&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=258" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:258px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</center>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are including the jQuery library twice, once for cantactable and once for facebook, remove the second one.

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/45yzC/

Comment: thanks its working now but as i removed jquery lib from fb box it slow down the loading process of like box of facebook btw thanks for ur valuable reply

Comment: sabit hi i need your help again same problem but this time feed back form is not visible i tried everything but stil its not worked please help me reply me i will show u the code thankyou once again